# Solution of the second-order ODE with polynomial coefficients $(a-x)\,x\, y''(x)+\left(\frac{a}{2}-2 \,x\right)y'(x)+\lambda \,x^2y(x)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am searching for solutions of the following second order differential equation:

> $$(a-x)\,x\, y''(x)+\left(\frac{a}{2}-2 \,x\right)y'(x)+\lambda \,x^2y(x)=0,\qquad (0<x<a)$$
>   with $y(a)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$.

As far as I know, there is no finite polynomial solution. In a book I have found a solution when the factor $x^2$ in the last term is replaced by 1.

**EDIT**: Boundedness of $y(x)$ for $x\to 0$ is an alternative condition (instead of $y'(0)=0$).

Comment: If the Wolfram Dev Platform doesn't give you a closed-form solution, there probably isn't one. If you have to have an exact solution, then a series method is your only option, most likely. Otherwise, of course, you could always go numerical.

Comment: Even with series, the condition $y(a)=0$ would make the problem very difficult.

Comment: @Claude is there an alternative condition which brings out a closed form solution?

Comment: I don't think so, I am afraid .... except with $\lambda=0$ (joke !). Even with $x^2$ replace by $1$ as you mentionned, the result is quite ugly.

Comment: Maple 2018.1 gives general solution with [HeunC function](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=HeunC) adding boundary conditions: $y(a)=0$,$y'(0)=0$ spit up one solution: $y(x)=0$

Comment: Do you have the general solution? (I am not a Maple user)

Comment: $$y \left( x \right) ={\frac {{\it \_C1}\,{{\rm e}^{\sqrt {\lambda}x}}}{
\sqrt {x-a}}{\it HeunC} \left( 2\,a\sqrt {\lambda},-1/2,-1/2,-\lambda
\,{a}^{2},1/8,{\frac {x}{a}} \right) }+{\frac {{\it \_C2}\,{{\rm e}^{
\sqrt {\lambda}x}}\sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {x-a}}{\it HeunC} \left( 2\,a\sqrt 
{\lambda},1/2,-1/2,-\lambda\,{a}^{2},1/8,{\frac {x}{a}} \right) }
$$ where:  $\_C1$,$\_C2$ integration constans.